# Typescript in nodejs/koa, is it safe to target ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am migrating to use typescript in a nodejs/koa project. I found I have to change the .tsconfig to target es6, otherwise it will complain:  **Generators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher**.

```
// index.ts
let koa = require('koa');
let app = koa();
export {app};

app.use(function *(){
    return yield this.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3090);

// .tsconfig
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5", // I have to switch to es6 to pass
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

Though it works for es6, but I am worrying about if nodejs runtime cover es6 features fully (I was told the coverage percentage is 96% something). I am wondering why I cannot target es5, since typescript is a transpiler, it should be able to compile generator to promise like babel did?

By the way, I already tried installing es6-shim typing without lucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering why I cannot target es5, since typescript is a transpiler, it should be able to compile generator to promise like babel did

They are in the process of rewritting the *emit* portion of TypeScript to use `plugins` like babel does: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5595 Essetially just code that isn't completely written yet.

> I am worrying about if nodejs runtime cover es6 features fully (I was told the coverage percentage is 96% something).

At this point it is safe to do this for NodeJS! See https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ (server runtimes / node6 column )

Comment: Excellent, cannot wait for the plugins feature, just checked the roadmap, it will come in 2.1. Besides, the coverage of nodejs is 93%, I think we still need to be careful somehow. By the way, could you recommend some best practices  links about nodejs with typescript?

Comment: For dev mode, we can target es6. For production IMO we can use typescript compile to es6, and finally use babel-node to build to es5 for safety.